# How should a properly UTF-8 encoded file look in notepad++

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I am integrating data using some flat files. I'm getting the flat files delivered by FTP as .csv-files out of MS SQL exports from a business partner.

I asked him to encode it as UTF-8 (just using the standard I thought).
Now I can see in his files that a lot of UTF-8 bytes such as "& # 2 3 3 ;" (w/o the spaces) can be seen as plain text when I open it in Notedpad++ (or also using my "ETL" tool).

Before I ask him to fix it into proper UTF-8, I would like to understand the issue and whether my claim is actually correct?

Shouldn't special characters be shown as special characters when I open them in Notepad++ and not as plain text UTF-8 codes?

Any help is much appreciated :))

Cheers
Martin

Comment: May I interest you in [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for a definition of what UTF-8 actually is?

Answer (score 0):

`&#233;` is an **HTML entity**. For some reason the text is HTML formatted, which I wouldn't count as "plaintext"/flat files. The file may or may not be encoded in UTF-8 in addition to that, we don't know from the information given.

A file containing "special characters" (meaning non-ASCII characters) encoded in UTF-8 opened in a text editor which correctly interprets the file as UTF-8 looks exactly like the text it should look like, e.g.:

> 正式名称は、ISO/IEC 10646では “UCS Transformation Format 8”、Unicodeでは “Unicode Transformation Format-8” という。両者はISO/IEC 10646とUnicodeのコード重複範囲で互換性がある。RFCにも仕様がある。

Put this in a file, save it as UTF-8, open it in another application *as UTF-8*, and this is what the text should look like.